# How to feed a String to a Google Cloud Function as input?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, google-cloud-platform

I need a Google Cloud Function that I can call from my Android app. The function should call Vision API Safe Search and return the results to the app.

My problem: The function I have is simple and it works. But ONLY from the Cloud Test-Console. Not from the android app. When I call the function from my app, with the exact same JSON as input, it says `FirebaseFunctionsException: INVALID_ARGUMENT`

**Function**:

```
exports.starte = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let pfad = req.body.pfad;
    console.log('Input is: ' + pfad);

    // Imports the Google Cloud client libraries
    const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');

    // Creates a client
    const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

    const visionRequest = {
      features: [
        { type: 'SAFE_SEARCH_DETECTION' },
      ],
      image: { source: { imageUri: pfad } },
    };
    const [result] = await client.annotateImage(visionRequest);
    const detections = result.safeSearchAnnotation;
    
    console.log('Ergebnis: ' + result);
    console.log('Ergebnis: ' + detections);

    res.status(200).send(detections);

  } catch(err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err.message);
    const errorJSON = { message: 'unknown' };
    res.status(400).send(errorJSON);
  }
};
```

**Android code**:

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("pfad", path);

FirebaseFunctions.getInstance()
        .getHttpsCallable("nsfw_test2")
        .call(data)
        .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, String>() {
            @Override
            public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
                try {
                    Object result = task.getResult().getData();
                    Log.v(TAG, "CloudFunktion: Worked!");
                    return result.toString();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.v(TAG, "CloudFunktion: Failed!");
                    return e.getMessage();
                }
            }
        });
```

Example JSON input that works in the Cloud Console, but not in Android:
`{"pfad":"gs:\/\/xxx.appspot.com\/photos\/xxx"}`

Error I get in Android:

```
com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctionsException: INVALID_ARGUMENT
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.getResult(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:3)
```

---

When I check the logs in Google Cloud, it logs: `Input is: undefined` (When running from the app)

When I run it from the Cloud Console instead, it works and prints the path I passed.

---

I have absolutely no idea why this happens. I have now checked easily 30 websites and stackoverflow questions on this. To me it seems that my Android code is correct.

But why doesn't the function read the input then? Why is the input `undefined`? The input in the android app is not `null`, I log the input before I pass it in, and it is the correct file.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/functions/FirebaseFunctionsException.Code), the invalid argument is because we failed to specify an argument correctly:

> public static final FirebaseFunctionsException.Code INVALID_ARGUMENT
>
> Client specified an invalid argument. Note that this differs from
> FAILED_PRECONDITION. INVALID_ARGUMENT indicates arguments that are
> problematic regardless of the state of the system (e.g., an invalid
> field name).

You need to create callable functions, instead of using an HTTP triggered Cloud Function.

The [Callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) require to have the following format:

```
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // ...
});
```

It's not the same as an [HTTP triggered Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) (which is what you are using). You can still access it if you use an HTTP request from the Android app, but you need to use a Callable Cloud Function.

Comment: Hello Lukas, was the information of any use?